Getting cors error while trying MFE using Angular Module Federation
I have created a MFE architectture using module federation in angular.
I have two project one is host and another one is remoteapplazy2.These two are normal angular project.Only in remoteapplazy2 project I added a lazy load module named contact.
In host project I added the module-federation library using
    `ng add @angular-architects/module-federation@16 --project host --port 4200`

In remoteapplazy2 project I added the module-federation library using
    `ng add @angular-architects/module-federation@16 --project remoteapplazy2 --port 5002`

Now I have configured the webpack.config.ts for remoteapplazy2 project:
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "remoteapplazy2",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },   
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: "module" },

        // For remotes (please adjust)
        name: "remoteapplazy2",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
            './lazyComponent': './/src/app/contact/contact.module.ts',
        },        
        
        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })
        
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};


Now in host app ,as I'm using lazy loading module,I configured the app-routing.module.ts :
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AdminComponent,
},{
  path: 'contacts',
  loadChildren: () =>
    loadRemoteModule({
      type: 'manifest',
      remoteName: 'contactsMfe',
      exposedModule: './lazyComponent',
    }).then((m) => m.ContactModule),
},];


In mf.manifest.json I stored the remote configured file:
{
    "contactsMfe": "http://localhost:5002/remoteEntry.js",
  }

Now when I start those two project using ng serve it's working fine.
But If I build the remoteapplazy2 using ng build and put the files inside a nodeserver running on 5002 and running the host app using ng serve I'm geting CORS error.
Access to script at 'http://localhost:5002/remoteEntry.js' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Adding the app.js for nodeserver :
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');



var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

var root = __dirname + "/public";
var port = 5002;

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(root));
app.use(cookieParser());

/*CORS middleware */
/*app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('inside cors')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
    next();
});*/
app.use(cors());
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:4200' }));

app.use(nocache);
app.use(errorHandler({
    dumpExceptions: true,
    showStack: true
}));

function nocache(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.header('Expires', '-1');
    res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    next();
}
require('./serverRoute')(app);

app.listen(port);

console.log("server running on " + port);


Serverroute.js :

const path = require('path')
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/',function (req,res) {
        console.log('Inside Test')
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
    });
}

But I can directly open the js file from Browser.
Also I created a test.html for testing:
<html>
    <body>Test
        <script src="http://localhost:5002/remoteEntry.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

But no cors issue this time.
This cors error is coming for any nodeserver configuration error or There is another process to build MFE architechture not like normal ng build?
